# Integrating JavaScript's .bind() with callback function

Tags: javascript, bind

So, below is a very barebones example of a case where I'd set `that` to `this` so I can use the scope of `myObj`. How would I integrate Function.prototype.bind, just so I can see how I can use it in the future?

```
var myObj = {

        specialFunction: function () {

        },

        anotherSpecialFunction(){

        },

        getAsyncData: function (cb) {
            // an operation
            cb();
        },

        render: function () {
            var that = this;
            this.getAsyncData(function () {
                that.specialFunction();
                that.anotherSpecialFunction();
            });
        }
    };

    myObj.render();
```

Comment: `that` would give the scope of `render` function in your case and not of `myObj`

Comment: @Vandesh I don't think you're right there...

Comment: Where is `getAsyncData` defined? Is it suppose to be myObj.getAsyncData?

Comment: @Musa Yes, sorry. Type whilst typing up code...

Comment: @benhowdle89 : correct. My bad! Verified here - http://jsfiddle.net/FKduF/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use bind on the method you want and specify the context

```
render: function () {
    this.getAsyncData(this.specialFunction.bind(this));
}
```

---

```
    render: function () {
        this.getAsyncData(someFunction.bind(this));
        function someFunction() {
            this.specialFunction();
            this.anotherSpecialFunction();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's cool. Maybe I made it too contrived. I've edited it to reflect what I'd be more likely to do in a real life use case.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I integrate Function.prototype.bind

Omit `that`, use `this` instead and bind the function to the instance:

```
…
    render: function () {
        this.getAsyncData(function () {
            this.specialFunction();
            this.anotherSpecialFunction();
        }.bind(this));
    }
…
```

> just so I can see how I can use it in the future?

You can use it right now. Every decent browser supports it, and if you really care about old Internet Explorers and the like you can [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted `this` to still refer to `myObj` inside the callback function passed to `getAsyncData` you'd want your `render` function to look like this:

```
render: function () {
    this.getAsyncData((function () {
        this.specialFunction();
        this.anotherSpecialFunction();
    }).bind(this));
}
```